# Crear un nuevo array de carácteres con los 2 primeros valores de otros 2

Tags: java, array

Mi idea es, a partir de 2 `arrays` de caracteres creados a partir de dos `Strings`, crear un nuevo `array` que contenga los `2` primeros valores de cada uno de los `arrays`, que tengo creados previamente, para después convertir ese nuevo `array` en un tercer `String`.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
//Creamos las cadenas
String nombre = "Paco";
String apellidos = "Maravilla";

//Creamos el array con los chars de la cadena:
char[] array_nombre = nombre.toCharArray();
char[] array_apellidos = apellidos.toCharArray();

//Los mostramos por pantalla
for(int i=0; i<array_nombre.length; i++){
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + " = " + array_nombre[i]);
}
System.out.println("---------");
for(int i=0; i<array_apellidos.length; i++){
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + " = " + array_apellidos[i]);
}

//Creamos nuevo array con los 2 primeros valores de cada array anterior
char[] array_apodo = array_nombre[0] + array_nombre[1] 
    +array_apellidos[0] + array_apellidos[1];
```

Creo que está correcto, pero el Eclipse me da el siguiente error en la última línea:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char[] Line breakpoint

¿Es posible solucionar esto?

Comment: A efectos de java, estás intentando realizar la siguiente suma  `array_nombre[0] + array_nombre[1] +  array_apellidos[0] + array_apellidos[1]` por lo que java espera realizar una suma de enteros. Deduzco que tu intención es concatenar los elementos del array, sin embargo el operador concatenación solo funciona con el tipo *String*.

Comment: un string(cadena)  es desde ya un array, no entiendo para que conviertes tantas veces

Comment: @rn3w puede ser una tarea o algo asi, para identificar tipos de datos o algo asi

Answer (score 3):

Lo que esta intentando hacer el compilador es sumar los elementos y no concatenarlos como tu piensas. Ademas, no es posible agregar 4 elementos a un `char`

```
char[] array_apodo = array_nombre[0] + array_nombre[1] +  array_apellidos[0] + array_apellidos[1];
```

Lo que deberias hacer es si quieres concatenados los valores es :

```
char[] array_apodo = new char[4];
String nuevo = array_nombre[0] + "" + array_nombre[1] + "" + array_apellidos[0] + "" + array_apellidos[1];
array_apodo = nuevo.toCharArray();   
for(int i=0; i<array_apodo.length; i++){
    System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + " = " + array_apodo[i]);
}
```

Otra de las forma es simplemente es generar un arreglo `char[]` y asignar tus valores como `array`

```
char[] array_apodo = {array_nombre[0], array_nombre[1], array_apellidos[0], array_apellidos[1]};
for(int i=0; i<array_apodo.length; i++){
   System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + " = " + array_apodo[i]);
}
```

De esta manera `char[] array_apodo = {array_nombre[0], array_nombre[1], array_apellidos[0], array_apellidos[1]};` defines el arreglo que necesitas y no concatenas los valores de tus arreglos.